# Glitch using drillthrough and action

Tags: powerbi

I am having trouble with a Power Bi report I have built on the desktop version.

I have a page with a graph and a button and a second page with a table of data. The button has an action to go to the bookmarked data page and the graph has a drillthrough linked to the data page.

When I open up the report and click on the button, it works correctly, then I click on the graph drillthrough and that works correctly too. But, when I then go back to the button and click it again, it shows whatever was last showing on the drillthrough from the graph. I have to exit the report to be able to show the full table using the button.

I have tried removing ticks from the bookmark, I have removed data and display, but this hasn't fixed it. I am new to Power Bi so I am not sure what to try next.

Comment: Have you tried setting the bookmark up to keep filters? And save the bookmark when no filters are applied.

Comment: I have set the bookmark up so that it only has ticks on the current page and all visuals, all others are not ticked. bookmark is saved with no filter on.

Comment: Okay. Why don't you try saving it with the filters you want, aka none applied?

Comment: I can't do that as it's dynamic. The graph will change and therefore will need to show different list depending on what bar is clicked on, and then when the button is clicked it needs to show the whole list.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm suggesting. The bookmark saves no-filter state. So every time you click on its button, you are taken to the drill-through page with no filters. When using drill-through, the filter will apply.

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in comments, the default bookmark settings that include data and page should work for your case. I have done exactly what you described in your post. I have two pages: Page1 with summary chart and bookmark button; Page2 which is a drill-through.

I have configured a bookmark with default settings and saved it on the drill-through page with no filters applied. I then do this:

1. Page1 drill-through to store=500
2. See Page2 filtered
3. Navigate to Page1
4. Click bookmark button
5. See Page2 unfiltered.

Here is my bookmark config. Note the bookmark was saved on the drill-through page with no filters applied:
[image: bookmark config]

Here is what I see when I drill-through on store 500:
[image: drill-through on store 500]

And then I navigate to page 1 again. I click on the button attached to the bookmark and I see this on the drill-through page:
[image: drill-through page from bookmark button]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I agree, that this does work, however I have had to remove the 'data' tick from all of my bookmarks, as I have several pages, witha front page and drill downs, and in order for the filters to stick on each page, the 'data' has to be unticked. this means I can only do one or the other, so I have got round it by creating two separate drill down pages which are identical, one for the graph and one for the total button. It's a pain but it's the only way I have been able to get it to work.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue you seem to be having. I have a slicer on my primary page. I have my bookmark set on the drillthrough page. I have saved the bookmark on the drillthrough page when the main page slicer was cleared. If I select a slicer on the primary page; then click the button for the bookmark to the drillthrough page; then come back to the primary page, the slicer is unaffected - it preserves whatever selection I had made. The same with page-level filters, and synced slicers. If I set report-level filters, I can simply make my bookmark apply to selected visuals.